# Wordpress - Get all posts without image?

Tags: mysql, image, wordpress

is there any way to find all the post without any associated images (neither inline or attachment) from Sql?

Or anyone can explain me how does wordpress store the images cause it is not so clear to me. I found out that they could be inline in text or stored in wp_postmeta with meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" or in wp_posts with post_type = "attachment".

Is this right?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the posts are returned as an object. Within that object is the featured image ID, as the image is also stored as its own post. just return the object keys minus the featured image one.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress manages media (images,text documents, etc) by creating an [attachment post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Attachment) for holding the information about that media and it's relation (if any) with other post/posts.

To retrieve all posts without any image attached you can execute a query like this:

```
select * from wp_posts where id not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_thumbnail_id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I've added:

```
AND ID not in (select post_id as p from wp_postmeta where meta_key like "_wp_attached_file")
```

but it still return too many results.

I've seen that in post_content of my results I've some images declared like:

```
<img src="/public/Username/filename.jpg">
```

And that query doen't exlude that post. I got a good result using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID), p.post_title, p.post_content FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN wp_posts im ON p.ID = im.post_parent AND im.post_type = "attachment" 
WHERE p.post_status ='publish' 
    AND p.post_type = "post" 
    AND im.ID IS NULL
    AND p.post_content NOT REGEXP 'src=".*"'
```

Comment: There's an important difference to consider in response to this question. "without images" in the case of this example, would exclude any post that has an image tag in the body of the post. Another way would be to exclude posts associated with a Wordpress attachment. Because there's the option to do it either way, a complete answer may need to consider both cases. Voting this one up.